# Refresh Eclipse 4 RCP view on wizard perform finish

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

Rookie question that I'm not having much luck with.  In my e4 RCP application, I have a couple of instances where I create an object in a wizard that should then appear in one of my views.

The desired behavior is similar to how the eclipse Package Explorer View updates after a new project is created.

I was thinking I could just grab the view from the partService and run my own update method:

```
MPart ingredientsView = partService.showPart("com.personal.recipes.part.ingredientsview", PartState.ACTIVATE); 
IngredientsView iv = (IngredientsView) ingredientsView.getObject(); 
iv.updateView();
```

While this works in other places, when called from a wizard 'partService' is null and the app NPE's out.

So what is the proscribed method of forcing e4 views to update after modifying their contents?

EDIT: 
I tried to use the ContextInjectionFactory like @greg-449 showed in his answer, but I'm uncertain where to place it in my code, or how to define the context.  I'm launching the wizard from a toolbar button, and placed the following code in my handler:

```
    @Execute
public void execute(Shell shell) {
    IEclipseContext context = EclipseContextFactory.create();
    IWizard ingredientWizard = ContextInjectionFactory.make(IngredientWizard.class, context);

    WizardDialog wizardDialog = new WizardDialog(shell, ingredientWizard);
    wizardDialog.open();
    }
```

However, when I tried to get the part service with @Inject EPartService partService; I got an InjectionException saying no error was found.

Once injection is available, using the EventBroker looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Injection is only done on objects that the application model knows about. So it is not done on Wizards or Dialogs unless you do it 'manually' using `ContextInjectionFactory` when you create the dialog:

```java
IWizard wizard = ContextInjectionFactory.make(YourWizardClass.class, eclipseContext);

WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(shell, wizard);
```

This will do injection on your wizard class giving you access to the `EPartService`.

You could also use the 'event broker' (`IEventBroker`) to broadcast an event to anything that is interested rather than finding your specific view.

Comment: Your response led me to a rather simple solution.  I just injected the EPartService in my handler, grabber a reference to the view, and passed that to my wizard through its constructor.  Now I can call my refresh method no problem and it works like a charm.  The suggestion from @Stefan may be an even more elegant approach, so I'll look into creating a wrapper object in my model instead, and passing that to the wizard in the same manner.  That way I will have easy access to event calls.  Thanks so much for both of your help!

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`The best way to update a view is to use a model for the content of the view. Your wizard seems to allow editing or creating ingredients. When you perform the finish of your wizard you are probably modifying some ingredient data. The ingredient model should be informed of these changes. If the view uses a content provider that observes this model is will update automatically when the model sees the update (this is the observer pattern).
How this works depends on the nature of your data. You could use the PropertyChange-Support in Java.

To do so let the content provider implement the `org.eclipse.jface.util.IPropertyChangeListener` interface and fire property change events when the data is changed.

UPDATE

My ContentProvider implements the property change interface. Whenever a property change event is received the viewer is refreshed(asynchronously). All my persistence operations are handled by data managers similar to Fowler's the table data gateway pattern but sometimes for more than one table. The data manager fires the property change event. This way the UI (wizard) does not need to know about persistence

Comment: Thanks for the response @Stefan.  I do have a model in place using XCore, and use it to update my views and editors concerning existing objects.   But the problem I'm running into is getting the view to update when a *new* object is added.  The view simply holds a TreeViewer that makes a call to my database to build its contents.  What I want is to refresh the view after the user completes a wizard so it calls to the DB for any new data.  Am I able to add a listener directly to the TreeViewer?  How would I notify the view that an event has occurred that should result in a refresh?

Comment: @BiggPlanet Use the e4 event broker to broadcast events to anything that wants to handle them - see [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4EventSystem/article.html)

Comment: @BiggPlanet: My ContentProvider implements the property change interface. Whenever a property change event is received the viewer is refreshed(asynchronously). All my persistence operations are handled by data managers similar to Fowler's the table data gateway pattern but sometimes for more than one table. The data manager fires the property change event. This way the UI (wizard) does not need to know about persistence.